# How to create separate component for confirmation box in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working on angular 4 application and I have requirement of confirmation box. I want to use this confirmation box on listing, there is an icon in every row which will open the confirmation box on click but I also don't want that the HTML of confirmation box will repeat.

I want that HTML of confirmation box was written on one place & I will use that content on any listing component.

Example: On one listing page the HTML of confirmation box will load only one time & I will use that content as much as time I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one Component being the desired confirmation box and specify an `@input()` in its TypeScript, so you can feed data (maybe to which row this confirmation box belongs) into the component using HTML.

This way, your component is specified once with variables in it and may be displayed with different content. You were quite unspecific on which information should be dynamic and what the confirmation box should do, so I leave this link here, for futher reading about Component Interaction (I suppose this is what you need. Define once, use multiple times with different content).

Angular: Component Interaction - https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bootsrap modal

https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal

Define it once in your html like

```
<modal #myModal id="myModal">
    <modal-header [show-close]="true">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-body>
        <div>{{someBinding}}</div>
    </modal-body>
    <modal-footer>
         <input autofocus id="btModalYes" type="button" (click)="confirm()" value="Ok"/>
         <input id="btModalNo" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="myModal.dismiss()" value="Cancel">
    </modal-footer>
</modal>
```

then in your component you can change the text with a binding and open the modal

```
@ViewChild('myModal')
myModal: ModalComponent;

this.myModal.open();
```

You can also use this code in it's own component!

through an @Input tag you could pass the information and with an event emitter @Output you can inform the parent component about the action taken.

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter